# SwiftUI List and classes

Tags: swiftui-list

I created a simple list containing the names of customers. Each customer is a class:

```
import Foundation

class Customer: Identifiable, Hashable
{
  let name: String
  let vat: String

  init(name: String, vat: String?=nil) {
    self.name = name
    self.vat = vat ?? "Unspecified"
  }

  static func == (lhs: Customer, rhs: Customer) -> Bool {
    return (lhs.name == rhs.name) && (lhs.vat == rhs.vat)
  }

  func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(self.name)
    hasher.combine(self.vat)
  }

  func debugPrint() {
    print("Name: \(name), VAT: \(vat), id: \(id)")
  }
}

var customers = [
  Customer(name: "All"),
  Customer(name: "Customer 1"),
  Customer(name: "Customer 2"),
  Customer(name: "Customer 3"),
  Customer(name: "Customer 4"),
  Customer(name: "Customer 5")
]
```

Here is the list view:

```
@State private var multiSelection = Set<UUID>()

VStack() {
  Section("Customers") {
    List(customers, selection: $multiSelection) {
      Text($0.name)
     }
   }
}
```

Although the app runs fine, the List is not selectable
I need the List members be selectable
Since I am novice to swiftUI any help will be appreciated

PS: How I can make the List work with single selection?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the list will work with selection if I add the following code into the Customer class implementation:

```
let id = UUID()
```

But I get some compilation errors If I implement the Customer class as below:

```
class Customer: Identifiable, Hashable
{
  let name: String
  let vat: String

  init(name: String, vat: String?=nil) {
    self.name = name
    self.vat = vat ?? "Unspecified"
    self.id = UUID()
  }

  static func == (lhs: Customer, rhs: Customer) -> Bool {
    return (lhs.name == rhs.name) && (lhs.vat == rhs.vat)
  }

  func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(self.name)
    hasher.combine(self.vat)
  }

  func debugPrint() {
    print("Name: \(name), VAT: \(vat), id: \(id)")
  }
}
```

I get the following errors:

> Cannot assign to property: 'id' is a get-only property

> Cannot assign value of type 'UUID' to type 'ObjectIdentifier'

But if I change it as follows:

```
class Customer: Identifiable, Hashable
{
  let name: String
  let vat: String
  let id: UUID

  init(name: String, vat: String?=nil) {
    self.name = name
    self.vat = vat ?? "Unspecified"
    self.id = UUID()
  }

  static func == (lhs: Customer, rhs: Customer) -> Bool {
    return (lhs.name == rhs.name) && (lhs.vat == rhs.vat)
  }

  func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(self.name)
    hasher.combine(self.vat)
  }

  func debugPrint() {
    print("Name: \(name), VAT: \(vat), id: \(id)")
  }
}
```

I am confused and I don't know which is the right implementation. The first one or the last?

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The "Post Answer" button should be used only for complete answers to the question.